# How can I rotate and resize a video with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I use a programm that needs .mp4 video files in the resolution 1080x608 px (width x height).

My original videos have a smaller resolution - mostly 640x480 px.

I have to rotate my original videos 90 degree (CounterClockwise) and after the rotation resize to the resolution 1080x608 px. It should used the centered area of the video.

What is the correct command for ffmpeg?

For larger videos I use the following command:

```
md Jukebox_Converted-90_30fps_Audio_HD
cd Files_To_Be_Converted
for %%f in (*) do ..\ffmpeg -i "%%f" -vf "crop=608:1080:0:0,transpose=2" -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -c:a copy "..\Jukebox_Converted-90_30fps_Audio_HD\%%f"
pause
```

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

This will change the resolution of the videos without cropping them:

```
md Jukebox_Converted-90_30fps_Audio_HD
cd Files_To_Be_Converted
for %%f in (*) do ..\ffmpeg -i "%%f" -vf "transpose=cclock,scale=1080:608" -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -c:a copy "..\Jukebox_Converted-90_30fps_Audio_HD\%%f"
pause
```

Things I fixed about your command:

- Arbitrary Cropping
- Use of deprecated numeric value on transpose
- Wrong order of filters